# Simple query troubleshooting

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have a simple query that is erring out.  I cannot figure out why, as it is so simple.

The target data extension has a primary key on `contact_key`.

Both fields (unsubscribe & newsletter) from the source DE are bool fields.

```
    select 
      contact_key,
      email
    from preference_center
    where unsubscribe = 'true' 
      or newsletter = 'false'
```

Comment: Maybe it is just me but I think that this post is really difficult to understand.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick edited down to cut down on confusion.

Comment: Does it time out? or does it error fairly quickly?

Comment: 5 seconds or leas

Comment: Less*. Sorry. On mobile.

Comment: well good news is that it is not likely the actual query itself, since it is valid. I would check out that the target DE is correctly assigned, that there is no Pkey violations, that there are no duplicate records being returned (potentially messing up your Query Action), etc.

Comment: Ha!  So I’m not getting a “violation of primary key” error.  Even tested another DE without a primary key.    Is there something I’m missing when it comes to Boolean field validation using the OR logic?  Stripping out one of the where parameters yields results but together: error

Comment: so you have run it with each individually and each runs without error when alone?

Comment: They work independently, EXCEPT when I run `where newsletter = 'false'`.  `where newsletter = 'true'` works.

Comment: try replacing `= 'true'` with `IS TRUE` and `= 'false'` with `IS FALSE`. They SHOULD be near identical in context, but I have had weirder things happen. Could also try `newsletter != 'true'` if the true aspect seems to work, maybe that can be a 'workaround' but might need to add `or (newsletter != 'true' AND newsletter IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: @Gortonington SFMC sql doesn't version like/support `TRUE` or `FALSE` formatted that way.

Comment: Ok try `= 1` for true and `= 0` or `!= 1` for false then maybe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88324/discussion-between-tom-callahan-and-gortonington).

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this error, it's likely your data extension (source or target) that needs be modified.

In this case there was a sample record that did not meet the non-nullable criteria in the source data extension.  Therefore, the target data extension needed to have nullable fields.